# Need further explaining with a specific situation of .reduce() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this simple function:

```js
function exampleFn (firstArray, secondArray) {
  return firstArray.map((x, y) =>
    Math.abs(x - secondArray[y]))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b * b) / firstArray.length;
}
```

The function:

- accepts two integer arrays of equal length
- compares the value of each member in one array to the corresponding member in the other
- squares the absolute value difference between those two values
- and returns the average of those squared absolute value differences between each member pair.

It works with these values: [10, 20, 10, 2], [10, 25, 5, -2] //16.5 == 16.5.
Also works with: [-1, 0], [0, -1] //1 == 1.
**BUT it doesn't work with:** [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] //should be 9, instead returns 7

Why does this happen, and how do I fix this (I want to do this in only one line, long or short)? What do  I miss about .reduce()?

- [3, 3, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b*b) -----> returns 21 when I think it should return 27.

Comment: You haven't given an initial value to `.reduce()` so it's in fact calculating `3 + 3*3 + 3*3` - the first element of the array becomes the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through the reduce example that you included as the last part of your question:

```js
[3, 3, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b*b)
```

The reduce function gets called twice.

1. `a=3, b=3` executes `3 + 3 * 3`, yielding 12
2. `a=12, b=3` executes `12 + 3 * 3`, yielding 21

You're trying to calculate the sum of squares. You could first square each element, and then sum them like this:

```
[3, 3, 3].map(n => n * n)
         .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

That yields 27.

So, the solution to your whole function would look like this:

```js
function exampleFn (firstArray, secondArray) {
  return firstArray.map((x, y) => Math.abs(x - secondArray[y]))
                   .map(n => n * n)
                   .reduce((a, b) => a + b) / firstArray.length;
}

console.log(exampleFn([10, 20, 10, 2], [10, 25, 5, -2]) === 16.5)
console.log(exampleFn([-1, 0], [0, -1]) === 1)
console.log(exampleFn([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) === 9)
```

Comment: or just use `.reduce((a, b) => a + b * b, 0)`

Comment: Thank you! really didn't think of that.